# Sending "complex" model data over UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, rest, unity-game-engine

I am trying to consume some simple .NET API's in my Unity project. I have been able to populate models (classes) on the API server by specifying manually the name of each field. The issue is the content of these models are mainly primitive data types, mainly ints and strings. My model structures are going to require nested models (classes), for example:

```
public class Echo
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexData
{
    public List<Echo> echo { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

I have the exact same models in Unity, `serializable` and without the getters and setters as this is what I have seen done in my research.

So this is the code I am using to send this model, which is populated before being sent to this function (and confirmed by a breakpoint).
Keep in mind I have tried `WWWForm`, `Dictionary`, and `IMultipartFormSection`
data types to no avail. I have left them in the code simply to demonstrate what I have tried thus far:

```
IEnumerator sendComplexModel(string url, ComplexData complexData)
{
    string complex = JsonUtility.ToJson(complexData);

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("complexData", complex);

    Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    keyValuePairs.Add("complexData", complex);

    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("complexData", complex));

    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Something went wrong");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

You can assume that I have updated the parameters: `UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);` to use the relevant data structures I created above for testing

Every one of the overloaded functions for `UnityWebRequest` passes null to .NET as seen in this screenshot from Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio API]

What am I doing wrong? Is something like this even possible with the standard Unity libraries? I would prefer to stick to `UnityWebRequest` or whatever similar library is built into Unity.

Here is a side by side of the two models (classes), the left being the .NET API, the right being Unity:
[image: Side by side of client and api models]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

====================Update=======================

@LukeBriggs

I have implemented your code as follows, once again sanity check, adding a breakpoint before the web call to double-check I am actually sending a populated model.

This is how I've updated my code:

```
    string complex = JsonUtility.ToJson(complexData);
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, complex);
    uwr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Something went wrong");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
```

Visual Studio now throughs a null reference exception, while previously it would simply show the model properties/fields are null. Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your language is a bit confusing .. with "models" you seem to actually refer to `class`es and those are not "functions" but "fields"

Comment: @derHugo Sorry about that I have clarified my use of functions in an edit. The term model is just a specific use for a class in MVC coding pattern in which my API's are built, I'm just continuing this coding pattern in my Unity project.

Comment: Also just a general side note: Probably want to avoid calling stuff something like "ComplexData" because as your project grows it'll get confusing quickly. Always name your classes after what they represent. "UserProfileData" etc.

Comment: @LukeBriggs haha, fortunately, this is just for testing purposes

Comment: Awesome alright - just wanted to be sure :P

Comment: Updated answer in response to your edit - spotted something else in your code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Content-Type matters

Firstly, treat Unity just like any other client of a regular JSON API. The goal is then to get Unity to send JSON structured data.

> Tip: You can also create some JSON and post it to your API with tools like postman, curl etc or even just devtools in web browsers to test out the API side of things.

So, you're currently really close to that. The key part that is missing is simply your headers. When making a POST request, **you have to specify what the format of the data is** that you're actually sending - this is done by the `Content-Type` header. The standard default is a multipart form content type which crucially doesn't support this kind of nested data, but JSON does. Here's how you specify "I'm POSTing JSON" in Unity:

```
string jsonToSend = JsonUtility.ToJson(complexData);

UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, "");
uwr.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonToSend));
uwr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); // <--- The missing magic line
yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

..
```

## [FromBody] also matters

Over in your API, try adding the [FromBody] parameter attribute, like this:

```
public string getComplexData([FromBody] ComplexData complexData)
{
..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @LukeBriggs 
Somehow the model is still not being received by the API, however, weirdly on the API side, VS now throws a null reference exception, which it wasn't doing before. It would simply say the model fields are null.

Comment: I've just edited again with a change that makes it more universal for different versions of Unity - the .Post method has changed a couple times so the above should be good regardless of which version you're on :)

Comment: Re your PostMan tip, I have successfully gotten the following API's working in Unity, to the point where I can parse model data on the client-side, and post a model to the API with no nesting: 
`public ComplexData getComplexData(string text)`
`public string(Echo echo)`
I have also confirmed my API's are working with a Windows Console App using newtonsoft

Comment: Thank you so much, your last update fixed it! Been pulling my hair out the whole evening haha